# body on click element native js

Tags: javascript

In jquery, it is possible to bind actions to an element that does not yet exist, how to do this in native js?

```
$("body").on("input", ".element", function() {

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the `body` tag and attach event to it using `addEventListener`

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  if (e.target.id === 'element') {
    console.log(e.target.value)
  }

})
```

```html
<input class='element' id='element'>
```

Comment: `document.body` is enough, no need to crawl the DOM, create a live collection, and access its `0` index to have the body.